# HTTPRequest for forum login - Objective C

Tags: objective-c, authentication, httprequest, forum

I am trying to implement this code in Objective C:

```
Public Shared Function Login(ByVal Username As String, ByVal Password As String) As Boolean
    Dim str As String = Func.ConvertToHex(Username)
    Http.GetResponse("http://www.website.com/forum/login.php?do=login", String.Concat(New String() { "vb_login_username=", str, "&vb_login_password=", Password, "&cookieuser=1&s=&securitytoken=guest&do=login&vb_login_md5password=&vb_login_md5password_utf=" }))
    If Http.ResponseValue.Contains(("Thank you for logging in, " & Username)) Then
        Http.GetResponse("http://www.website.com/forum/usercp.php")
        Return True
    End If
    Return False
End Function
```

This is what I've already done:

```
- (IBAction)loginButton:(id)sender {
    NSURL *loginURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.website.com/forum/login.php?do=login"];
    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:loginURL];
    [request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setUseKeychainPersistence:YES];

    [request addPostValue:[self.usernameField stringValue] forKey:@"vb_login_username="];
    [request addPostValue:[self.passwordField stringValue] forKey:@"&vb_login_password="];

    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request setTimeOutSeconds:60];
    [request startSynchronous];
    [request setUseSessionPersistence:YES];
}

- (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request {
    NSLog(@"Request failed: %@",[request error]);
}

- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    NSLog(@"Submitted form successfully");
    NSLog(@"Response was:");
    NSLog(@"%@",[request responseString]);
}
```

But it does not work..
I get a reply back but not as a member.

P.S. It's about a vBulletin Forum
Sorry for my bad english..

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Hard to try to reproduce with no server to test. However two things:

1. lib which you use is depreciated, consider moving for other (for example AFNetworking)
2. in second parameter you have "&vb_login_password=" I believe there should be no '&' character. Also try to remove '=' at end.

If there is no HTTPS you can use wireshark to check packets from program which work, and from your version. Then compare both request and seek for differences.

Answer (score 0):

It now works. I've added some more entries.

```
[request addPostValue:@"1" forKey:@"cookieuser"];
[request addPostValue:@"login" forKey:@"do"];
[request addPostValue:@"" forKey:@"s"];
[request addPostValue:@"guest" forKey:@"securitytoken"];
[request addPostValue:@"" forKey:@"vb_login_md5password"];
[request addPostValue:@"" forKey:@"vb_login_md5password_utf"];
[request addPostValue:[self.passwordField stringValue] forKey:@"vb_login_password"];
[request addPostValue:[self.usernameField stringValue] forKey:@"vb_login_username"];
```

I now get the HTML code from the forum back to a point where it says "Thank you for logging in, Username".